# Cannot run Embedded Pig using Java in MapReduce Mode

Tags: hadoop, configuration, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am using Pig 0.12.0 and Hadoop 2.2.0. I have successfully run pig from grunt shell and pig batch script in both local and map reduce mode. Now I am trying to run pig from embedded pig in Java.

With that said, I have also successfully run embedded pig in local mode. However, I run into problems running embedded pig in map reduce mode.

The problem is: After successfully compile class, nothing happened when I run

```
    java -cp <classpath> PigMapRedMode
```

I later saw people saying I should include pig.properties in the class path. Such as

```
    fs.default.name=hdfs://<namenode-hostname>:<port>
    mapred.job.tracker=<jobtracker-hostname>:<port>
```

However, in Hadoop 2.2.0, the JobTracker no longer exists. Any thoughts what to do?

I attached my Java code of PigMapRedMode in case there is something wrong here.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;

public class PigMapRedMode {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        try {
            PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("map reduce, (need to add properties file)");
            runIdQuery(pigServer, "5pts.txt");
        } catch (Exception e){
        }
    }

    public static void runIdQuery(PigServer pigServer, String inputFile) throws IOException {
        pigServer.registerQuery("A = load '" + inputFile + "' using PigStorage(',');");
        pigServer.registerQuery("B = foreach A generate $0 as id;");
        pigServer.store("B", "id.out");
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Solution has been found! Actually, no need for providing Properties object or using pig.properties in the class path, all you have to do is to include Hadoop configuration directories in the class path: (For my Hadoop 2.2.0, it is /etc/hadoop) and the df.default.address and yarn.resourcemanager.address could be retrieved from that place.

I attached the modified java code below:

```java
/**
 * Created by allenlin on 2/19/14.
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.pig.ExecType;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;


public class PigMapRedMode {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        try {
            PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE);
            runIdQuery(pigServer, "<hdfs input address>");
        } catch (Exception e){
        }
    }

    public static void runIdQuery(PigServer pigServer, String inputFile) throws IOException {
        pigServer.registerQuery("A = load '" + inputFile + "' using PigStorage(',');");
        pigServer.registerQuery("B = foreach A generate $0 as id;");
        pigServer.store("B", "<hdfs output address>");
    }
}
```

The Unix command that I use to run the java class. Be careful for the dependancies you need to include:

```
java -cp ".:$PIG_HOME/build/pig-0.12.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:antlr-runtime-3.4.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$PIG_HOME/build/ivy/lib/Pig/*:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR" PigMapRedMode
```

Thanks for @zsxwing help!

Comment: Here is how I create a Properties. `Properties properties = new Properties(); PropertiesUtil.loadDefaultProperties(properties); properties.putAll(ConfigurationUtil.toProperties(conf));` Can you try it?

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try and let you know!

Comment: Hi @zsxwing Thanks for your reply but one question, where to how to get Hadoop Configuration file?

Comment: @zsxwing or could you give me a workable embedded pig java code to run under MapReduce mode? Thanks!

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer and accept it... sadly I'm getting the same problem but the same solution doesn't work :(, it just runs in local mode regardless of what I do

Comment: @fd8s0 Hi, what's wrong in your situation? Although it has been almost a year, I am willing to see if I could help out :)

Comment: it was a problem with CDH 5.0.3 libraries... moving to 5.1.3 fixed the issue, somehow it wouldn't recognise YARN and it'd not find a jobtracker and thus execute in local mode, it was very painful and fixed by just randomly trying upgrades (as pig 0.13.0 non-cdh had other issues).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i ran Embedded Pig

```
public class test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {
        PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE);
        runQuery(pigServer);
         Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
}catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void runQuery(PigServer pigServer) {
    try {
        pigServer.registerQuery("input1 = LOAD '/input.data' as (line:chararray);");
        pigServer.registerQuery("words = foreach input1 generate FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as word;");
        pigServer.registerQuery("word_groups = group words by word;");
        pigServer.registerQuery("word_count = foreach word_groups generate group, COUNT(words);");
        pigServer.registerQuery("ordered_word_count = order word_count by group desc;");
        pigServer.registerQuery("store ordered_word_count into '/wct';");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

set HADOOP_HOME in eclipse

```
Run Configurations-->ClassPath-->User Entries-->Advanced-->Add ClassPath Variables-->New-->Name(HADOOP_HOME)-->Path(You Hadoop directory path)
```

Maven dependencies i have added

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
    <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
    <version>0.15.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

If you do not set HADOOP_HOME properly, you will get the following error

```
hadoop20.PigJobControl: falling back to default JobControl (not using hadoop 0.20 ?)
```